# DevExtreme Exporter prints blank page

Tags: devexpress, chart.js, devextreme

I am using DevExtreme dxExporter to export charts to pdf/png/svg. I followed all the steps they provided [here](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Visualization/Common/Widget_Export/), from `Deploy a Server` up to `Tune dxExporter`.

Everything looks fine, my PhantomJS is ready(perfoms as a server to allow me to use the client-server model), see below:

[image: PhantomJS]

The print and export icons are also showing as expected :
[image]

Now the problem is, when I try to export a chart to pdf/png/svg, the browser downloads the desired file, but it is blank, as a results it fails to open.

if you have experienced this before, can you please tell me what could be the problem and how to fix it.

Here is my chart container and `dxExporter` div:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 440px;"></div>
<div id='exportMenu'></div>
```

Here is my `dxExporter` code:

```
$("#exportMenu").dxExporter({ 
        sourceContainerId:"#container",
        serverUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:3003"
       });
```

`PDF` results:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `sourceContainerId` option in your code, but in last versions this option has name [`sourceContainer`](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxExporter/Configuration/?version=14_2#sourceContainer). Try to replace it and maybe this will help you.